# Sum of its parts - replicating a porcelain sculpture of Nuala O’Donovan

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, generative-art

**1. Introduction**

Nuala O’Donovan is an Irish Artist, living and working in Cork. According to her [website](https://nualaodonovanartist.com/) her research areas are *"Irregularities in Patterns in Nature"* and *"The Geometry of Natural Forms"*.

[image]

*Radiolaria Grid series, High fired porcelain, unglazed. Nuala O’Donovan 2015*

[image]

*Radiolaria Grid series – interior detail –*

**2. Question**

I would like to replicate with Mathematica Nuala's sculpture pictured below. It is made of small porcelain tubes and called *"The sum of its parts"*. A rectangular exterior turns into a mikado-like chaos as we move inside.

[image]

*Nuala O’Donovan, The sum of its parts*

I began with the interior:

```
Graphics3D[
 Table[{
   MaterialShading[<|"BaseColor" -> White, "RoughnessCoefficient" -> 0.1 |>],
   Cylinder[RandomReal[40, {2, 3}]]}, {60}],
 Boxed -> False,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2},
 Background -> GrayLevel[0],
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint"]
```

[image]

and immediately (as usual) got a problem:

- Due to the changed `BoxRatios`, the tubes appear to be oval rather
  than round, and I don't know how to fix this distortion.
- The next question is how we can "surround" the inner randomly scattered "mikados" with a rectangular outside structure. How to get the *"sum of its parts"*, so to say.
- And a third (non-essential) question: Would it be possible to give the background a grayish gradient-like appearance like in the above photo?

Comment: Interesting, do you know the material of these objects?

Comment: Try [ClipPlanes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html) instead of adjusting bounding box.

Comment: Thanks, Yarchik, ClipPlanes might be a good idea. Will try later. The objects are made of  high fired  unglazed porcelain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- We select random points in the cube and select random directions  to draw infinitelines and cut their by the `PlotRange`.
- We use `DiscretizeRegion` to the boundary of cube and extend the lines to  infinitelines, after that we also cut it by `PlotRange`.
- Finally we use `DiscretizeGraphics` to get all the lines.

```
reg = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 3, 5}];
n = 60;
pts = RandomPoint[reg, n];
dirs= RandomPoint[Sphere[], n];
interior = 
  Graphics3D[MapThread[InfiniteLine, {pts, dirs}], 
    PlotRange -> RegionBounds[reg], Boxed -> False] // 
   DiscretizeGraphics;
δ = 1.2;
faces = Graphics3D[
    MeshPrimitives[#, 
        1] & /@ (DiscretizeRegion[#, 
          MaxCellMeasure -> "Area" -> δ] & /@ 
        MeshPrimitives[RegionBoundary@reg, 2]) /. 
     Line -> InfiniteLine, PlotRange -> RegionBounds[reg], 
    Boxed -> False] // DiscretizeGraphics;
Graphics3D[{MeshPrimitives[faces, 1] /. Line -> Tube, 
  MeshPrimitives[interior, 1] /. Line -> Tube}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- For non convex region.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg = RegionProduct[Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}, {0, 3 Pi/2}], 
   Line[{{0}, {1.}}]];
n = 60;
pts = RandomPoint[reg, n];
dirs = RandomPoint[Sphere[], n];
interior = 
  Table[Tube[{pts[[i]] + #[[1]]*dirs[[i]], 
       pts[[i]] + #[[-1]]*dirs[[i]]}] & /@ 
    Flatten@List[
      Reduce[Rationalize[pts[[i]] + s*dirs[[i]] ∈ reg, 0], 
        s] /. Or -> List], {i, 1, n}];
lines = MeshPrimitives[
    BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> ∞], 
    1][[;; , 1]];
faces = Table[
   Tube[{line[[1]] + #[[1]]*(line[[2]] - line[[1]]), 
       line[[1]] + #[[-1]]*(line[[2]] - line[[1]])}] & /@ 
    Flatten[List[
        Reduce[Rationalize[
           line[[1]] + s*(line[[2]] - line[[1]]) ∈ reg, 0], 
          s] /. Or -> List] /. s == 0 -> Nothing /. 
      False -> Nothing], {line, lines}];
Graphics3D[{interior, faces}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- Another non convex regions.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg = ConcaveHullMesh[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1,
      1/3, 1/3}, {1, 2/3, 1/3}, {1, 1/3, 2/3}, {1, 2/3, 2/3}, {2, 0, 
     0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}];
bd = RegionBounds[reg];
n = 50;
pts = RandomPoint[reg, n];
dirs = RandomPoint[Sphere[], n];
interior = 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   Table[pts[[i]] + s*dirs[[i]], {i, 1, n}] // Evaluate, {s, -10, 10},
    PlotPoints -> 400, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t}, Element[{x, y, z}, reg]], 
   PlotRange -> bd];
faces = MeshPrimitives[RegionBoundary@reg, 2];
m = 8;
boundary = Table[
   With[{pts = RandomPoint[face, m]}, 
    ParametricPlot3D[
     Table[{1 - s, s} . {pts[[i]], pts[[j]]}, {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, i}] //
       Flatten, {s, -2, 2}, 
     RegionFunction -> 
      Function[{x, y, z, s}, {x, y, z} \[Element] reg], 
     PlotRange -> RegionBounds[reg], PlotRange -> bd]], {face, faces}];
Graphics3D[
 MeshPrimitives[
   Show[interior, boundary, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False] // 
    DiscretizeGraphics, 1] /. Line -> Tube, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[4];
cba = Flatten[#, 2] &@
   CoordinateBoundsArray[{{0, 3}, {0, 3}, {0, 5}}, 1] ;
{f1a, f1b} = GatherBy[cba, {#[[1]]} &][[{1, -1}]];
{f2a, f2b} = GatherBy[cba, {#[[2]]} &][[{1, -1}]];
{f3a, f3b} = GatherBy[cba, {#[[3]]} &][[{1, -1}]];
chm = ConvexHullMesh[cba + RandomReal[{-0.3, 0.3}, {96, 3}]];
cpts = RandomPoint[chm, 400] // Partition[#, 2] &;
cyls = Cylinder[#, RandomReal[{0.02, 0.05}]] & /@ cpts;

cyls1a = Cylinder[#, 
     RandomReal[{0.02, 0.05}]] & /@ (Tuples[f1a, 2] // 
      MaximalBy[#, Apply[EuclideanDistance], Length@#] &)[[1 ;; ;; 
      7]];

cyls1b = Cylinder[#, 
     RandomReal[{0.02, 0.05}]] & /@ (Tuples[f1b, 2] // 
      MaximalBy[#, Apply[EuclideanDistance], Length@#] &)[[1 ;; ;; 
      9]];

cyls2a = Cylinder[#, 
     RandomReal[{0.02, 0.05}]] & /@ (Tuples[f2a, 2] // 
      MaximalBy[#, Apply[EuclideanDistance], Length@#] &)[[1 ;; ;; 
      5]];

cyls2b = Cylinder[#, 
     RandomReal[{0.02, 0.05}]] & /@ (Tuples[f2b, 2] // 
      MaximalBy[#, Apply[EuclideanDistance], Length@#] &)[[1 ;; ;; 
      9]];

cyls3a = Cylinder[#, 
     RandomReal[{0.02, 0.05}]] & /@ (Tuples[f3a, 2] // 
      MaximalBy[#, Apply[EuclideanDistance], Length@#] &)[[1 ;; ;; 
      7]];

cyls3b = Cylinder[#, 
     RandomReal[{0.02, 0.05}]] & /@ (Tuples[f3b, 2] // 
      MaximalBy[#, Apply[EuclideanDistance], Length@#] &)[[1 ;; ;; 
      7]];

art = Graphics3D[{
   EdgeForm[None]
   , RGBColor[0.85, 0.83, 0.79] (* #FFF6E5 , RGBColor["#E3DAC9"]*)
   , cyls1a , cyls1b
   , cyls2a, cyls2b
   , cyls3a, cyls3b
   , cyls
   , AbsolutePointSize[6], Ball[#, RandomReal[{0.03, 0.07}]] &@cba
   }
  , SphericalRegion -> True
  , Lighting -> "Neutral"
  , Boxed -> False
  , ImageSize -> 600
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. @eldo

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
tube[l : {a : {x_, y_, z_}, b : {u_, v_, w_}}, s_ : 1] := Module[{}
   , {Tube[BSplineCurve[Subdivide[a, b, 30]]
      , RotateLeft[RandomReal[{.02, .048}, 30], RandomInteger[3]]]}];

slice[grid_ : {6, 4}, size_ : .15, deltaEdges_ : 100] := 
  Module[{gg, edges, vcoord, mesh},
    gg = GridGraph[grid];
    vcoord = VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[gg, VertexCoordinates];
    edges = RandomSample[
              Complement[UndirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[VertexList@gg, {2}], EdgeList@gg]
            , deltaEdges];
    mesh = MeshRegion[vcoord, Line[List @@@ edges]];
    tube[#] & /@ Map[# /. {x_, y_} :> {x - 1, y, RandomReal[size]} &, Sequence @@@ MeshPrimitives[mesh, 1], {2}]
];

SeedRandom[312];
Graphics3D[{
   MaterialShading[<|"BaseColor" -> White, "SheenColor" -> LightBlue
      , "SheenRoughnessCoefficient" -> .9, "RoughnessCoefficient" -> 0.9, "SpecularColor" -> Yellow|>]
   , slice[{6, 4}, 3., 140] (*Interior*)
   , FoldList[Rotate[#,  - 90  °, {0, 1, 0}, #2] &
      , slice[{6, 4}, .185, 65], {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}, {3, 0, 3}}] (*Sides*)
   , Rotate[slice[{4, 4}, .075, 55], 90 °, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}] (*Top*)
   , Rotate[slice[{4, 4}, .075, 55], 90 °, {1, 0, 0}, {0,  3.56, 2.54}] (*Bottom*)
  }
  , Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True
  , ViewPoint -> {-2.8, 1.3, 2.5}, ViewVertical -> {0, -1, 0}
  , Lighting -> "ThreePoint", ImageSize -> Large, 
 Background -> GrayLevel[0]]
```

[image]